# How to describe time dependence piece of a stationary state with average phase

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, time-evolution, atomic-clocks

I am reading this paper on the synchronization of atomic clocks via entanglement (https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0004105.pdf) and can't figure out how they are using $\Omega = (E_{1} - E_{o})/\hbar$  in place of the ordinary time dependence ${-iE_{n} t/\hbar}$. Where does the factor of 1/2 come from in the exponent? And how are they able to define this common phase factor?

For those who don't want to read the article, how do we replace $|pos\rangle=|0\rangle e^{-iE_ot/\hbar} + |1\rangle e^{-iE_1t/\hbar}$ with $|pos\rangle=|0\rangle e^{-i\Omega t/2} + |1\rangle e^{i\Omega t/2}$ where $\Omega$ is defined as $\Omega = (E_{1} - E_{o})/\hbar$

I can see the advantages of describing the time evolution of two stationary states through a common phase, but I can't figure out how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

I think they ignore an overall phase and did not write it explicitly
$$\begin{align}
|pos\rangle =& ~|0\rangle e^{-iE_0t/\hbar} + |1\rangle e^{-iE_1 t/\hbar} \\
=& ~e^{-i (E_0+E_1)t/2\hbar}\left( |0\rangle e^{-i\Omega t/2} + |1\rangle e^{i\Omega t /2} \right)
\end{align}$$